# Can't find relative MEF path when Directory root folder has space?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am getting my MEF specific dll like this:

```
string exeFile = (new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;

string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);

using (DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(exeDir,"Custom")))
{
   using (CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
   {

       container.ComposeParts(this);

   }
}
```

And this works if I am in development, but if I build and take the build output and put it in a folder called `c:\test 1`, when I run the app from `c:\test`, it says it can't find the `c:\test 1\custom` directory.

The `Custom` folder in the same path as the `EXE`

I noticed, it only can't find it if the directoy has a space in it like `test 1`, but it does work fine if it is just `test1`

If I run it with a space, I get the error:

`Could not find part of the path 'C:\TEST%202\CUSTOM\'.`

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.UnescapeDataString` worked?

I used as follows:

```
using (DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Uri.UnescapeDataString(path)))...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string exeFile = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
 string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile); 
 string path = Path.Combine(exeDir, "Custom");

 using (DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path))
 {
       using (CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
       {
          container.ComposeParts(this);
       }
 }
```

You should use Location instead of CodeBase ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx)).

MSDN Remarks:

> To get the absolute path to the loaded manifest-containing file, use
>   the Assembly.Location property instead.

Comment: What will show you this code? string absolutePath = (new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
            string location = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

            Console.WriteLine("AbsolutePath: {0}", absolutePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", location);

Comment: For absolutePath, I get `c:\test%202\test.exe` and for location I get `c:\test 2\test.exe`, so based on this, should I use Location instead?  What is the difference?

Comment: If I use `Location`, I know get the error:  `System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported`.

Comment: Do I have to escape the path? If so, how? I have tried the @ in front of exeFile and exeDir, but nothing works.

Comment: You get the error: "Could not find part of the path 'C:\TEST%202\CUSTOM\'" so what error you get when you use my code?

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported` is the error I get when I run your code

Comment: Could you give me value of properties exeFile, exeDir and path ?